# Urn experiment: pair-wise drawing of colored balls without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given an urn with **colored balls** from which we draw balls in a **pair-wise manner** (without replacement). If we draw $k$ pairs, what is the expected number of pairs with the same color?

Comment: What have you tried?  This seems like a good candidate for indicator variables and linearity of expectation.  Should say, though, that you don't provide nearly enough information.  How many colors are there?  How many balls of each color are there?

Comment: I am looking for a solution that will work for any number of colors and the number of balls of each color is also arbitrary. I don't have much of an idea of how to derive the math formula so if I don't find a solution soon, I will probably simulate the process and sample from it. (I need it for a practical problem.)

Comment: I told you how to solve it.  Use an indicator variable for each pair (they are all the same so you only have to do it once).

Comment: Apologies if I don't see an obvious point but how would an indicator variable help me? The main problem I see here is that the pairs are not independent since we are drawing without replacement.

Comment: Independence/dependence is irrelevant.  That's the point of Linearity of Expectation.  It holds regardless of any dependence in the variables.  I'll post something below.

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/#:~:text=Linearity%20of%20expectation%20is%20the,weighted%20average%20of%20possible%20outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say there are $n$ colors and that there are $B_i$ balls of color $i$.  Let $B=\sum B_i$ be the total number of balls.  Then the probability that both of the balls in a given pair have color $i$ is $\frac {B_i(B_i-1)}{B(B-1)}$  from which it follows that the probability that a given pair is monochromatic is $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac {B_i(B_i-1)}{B(B-1)}$$  As you are choosing $k$ pairs, Linearity of Expectation tells us that the expected number of single color pairs is therefore $$\boxed {k\times \sum_{i=1}^n\frac {B_i(B_i-1)}{B(B-1)}}$$

Sanity checks:  If there is only one color then $B_1=B$ so this is just $k$, as it should be.  If there are two colors with equal probability and infinitely many of each then the answer should be $\frac k2$ since each pair independently has probability $\frac 12$ of being single colored.  Our formula would give $$2k\lim_{b\to \infty}\frac {b(b-1)}{2b(2b-1)}=2k\times \frac 14=\frac k2$$ as desired.  Of course, it is easy to work out small cases by hand, or to simulate larger cases, and to thereby get additional numerical support for the formula.